# At what point does friendship become "queerbait"?

Tags: analysis, sherlock

I'm asking this specifically about BBC Sherlock, in regard to John and Sherlocks relationship. As a queer person, and as a fan of the show, I've been seeing a lot of complaints about 'Johnlock,' and how Moffat/Gatiss had the opportunity to make John and Sherlock a couple, but didn't. I'm aware what "queerbaiting" is-- It's defined on fanfare as

> In a fannish context, queer baiting (or queerbaiting) is a term used to describe the perceived attempt by canon creators (typically of television shows) to woo queer fans and/or slash fans, but with no intention of actually showing a gay relationship being consummated on screen.

However, **do Moffat/Gatiss have an "obligation," to romantically develop Johnlock when the show is an adaptation based on two straight men who are not interested in each other?**

What I've seen online, specifically on the Johnlock tag on Tumblr and on slash communities on Twitter, is that everybody is let down after this season because the writers heavily implied that there would be a m/m relationship and that their relationship was headed that way, and then it didn't happen. Fandom is upset that nothing was followed through with, which is where the queerbaiting part of my question is.

In the first episode of the show, John says he isn't gay, and Sherlock is heavily coded as asexual (until, I acknowledge, Johns wedding when he meets Janine). In addition, most of the 'proof,' that John and Sherlock are interested in each other is sourced from fan theories, dubious interpretations of interactions (I call such because *and this is a slight generalization* most of the shippers I've seen are straight girls), fandom projecting what they want to see onto the characters, and slowed down gifs. While I 100% agree that it would be awesome to see Johnlock, *there was nothing in the canon that suggested to me that it would be followed through with.*

Is it still queerbaiting if you know going in that it'll never happen? And does that change if the writers are very much aware that there *is* a queer interpretation of the the material (which, I believe, Moffat and Gatiss are)? **I'd like to know if the treatment of the show by the writers creates queerbait if the show itself does not**.

*The Daily Dot* writer, Gavia Baker-Whitelaw wrote an article (http://www.dailydot.com/parsec/sherlock-not-gay-steven-moffat-mark-gatiss/) that relates to this topic.

> Speaking to the blog With An Accent, showrunners Steven Moffat and Mark Gatiss tackled the long-running rumor that John and Sherlock will soon be a couple on the show. They sound pretty tired of the speculation, following a Comic-Con panel where Moffat spoke in general terms about writing gay characters on mainstream TV—which some fans then misinterpreted as a veiled hint about Sherlock.
>
> “It is infuriating frankly, to be talking about a serious subject and to have Twitter run around and say, 'Oh that means Sherlock is gay,'" said Moffat. "Very explicitly it does not. We are taking a serious subject and trivializing it beyond endurance.”
>
> "[Sherlock] explicitly says he is not interested," Gatiss said, referring to Sherlock's implied asexuality in the show. "Doesn’t mean he couldn’t be. Doesn’t mean there’s anything wrong with it. I’m a gay man. This is not an issue. But we’ve explicitly said this is not going to happen—there is no game plan—no matter how much we lie about other things, that this show is going to culminate in Martin [Freeman] and Benedict [Cumberbatch] going off into the sunset together."
>
> These quotes are a clear-cut denial, but some fans didn't just disagree with the interview—they doubted that it was even real. In the end, Mark Gatiss had to confirm on Twitter that no, the interview wasn't an elaborate fake.

One of the things that adds to the dubious treatment of John and Sherlocks relationship-- and this is discussed in the Daily Dot article I just referenced-- is the promotional strategy that BBC Sherlock adapted. Viewers are constantly encouraged to not overlook any detail, make their own conclusions, and read as much as possible into any situation. While this has been controversial in fandom (I remember when everyone lost their minds after, "Many Happy Returns," because Anderson, who obviously represented fandom, was mocked by Lestrade, who obviously represented the show) it also provided a sort of 'false hope,' that Johnlock might happen.

**In summary, I'm hoping somebody can definitively tell me whether or not Johnlock is queerbait, and if so, is it because of how the show was promoted and how the writers encouraged fandom responses, or if it's because of content within the show itself.**

Comment: Questions asking for opinions are off-topic. But it is something that can be discussed in Chat. Feel free to stick around and do so.

Comment: @John *Is* it asking for (unbacked) opinions?

Comment: I'd VTC as offensive, frankly.... in fact, I've flagged as such.

Comment: should i have flagged for slur? i don't see what's offensive about the question, but i apologize for it. i'm seeing that this isn't the right place for the question; should i close the thread?

Comment: @Tetsujin Thanks, declined. This doesn't seem to be offensive in any way. But fortunately you also know that you don't *close* questions for being offensive rather than *flagging* them as such.

Comment: @newt Don't worry.  It's not offensive.  Please don't remove your question.  It's very interesting.  It was already deemed completely appropriate.  Welcome to this community and thank you for your question :)

Comment: Don't worry, your question has been put on hold for now, since it might be a little too far on the open-ended or opinionated discussion spectrum. But that's not necessarily the end of it. Maybe you can tune the wording a little to invite less opinions and more well-argued discussion backed by the show, its themes, statements from its makers or existing critical analysis.

Comment: @newt You might want to remove the text about wanting to start a discussion and make the wording a little more clear that  you're looking for facts rather than opinion.  It seems the community thinks that it's primarily opinion based :)

Comment: You could also consider splitting the question up a little into multiple questions that can be tackled in a less broad and open-ended way. Sorry if this is a little overwhelming, but this site does have a few restrictions compared to more open-ended and subjective discussion forums. But this doesn't mean the considerations you put here aren't worth analysing.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson it is a little overwhelming but I really appreciate your advice! I'm pretty new to this and appreciate the help. I edited the format, is this better?

Comment: @Newt I like this question and I'm interested to see where it goes, but I think you need to better define what responses you are expecting to see here. Ultimately, what question are you asking? Are you looking to find out if *Sherlock* really is guilty of "queerbaiting"? Or just seeking a better definition of what "queerbaiting" is?

Comment: @DrRDizzle ok! I think i got it this time? I added a sentence at the end rephrasing my question and it's hopefully phrased in an open/shut way.

Comment: This is not a good question (in fact more of a disguised rant). The writers have been clear from the beginning that these characters are not gay. How to interpret the scenes as written is up to the viewer.

Answer (score 3):

LGBTQ subtext is super common in much media. Period.

With societal norms relaxing and LGBTQ visibility increasing, it seems inevitable that what was once virtually always subtext in film, television, books, has become more transparent and topical. From your Moffat/Gatiss quote:

> "[Sherlock] explicitly says he is not interested," Gatiss said,
>   referring to Sherlock's implied asexuality in the show. "Doesn’t mean
>   he couldn’t be. Doesn’t mean there’s anything wrong with it. I’m a gay
>   man. This is not an issue. But we’ve explicitly said this is not going
>   to happen—there is no game plan—no matter how much we lie about other
>   things, that this show is going to culminate in Martin [Freeman] and
>   Benedict [Cumberbatch] going off into the sunset together."

Sexuality is a sensitive area and despite the normalization of the [LGBTQ community on the rise](http://thehill.com/homenews/campaign/246695-young-republicans-say-party-risks-losing-millennials-after-gay-marriage), its depiction in media is still evolving. I would take him at his word about the evolution of these characters, keeping in mind, the time period in which Sherlock is set and how unthinkable it might be for the characters themselves.

If Moffat/Gatiss are using sexuality innuendo as a 'tease' to engage gay viewers, it may just be a marketing tool to bring more eyes to the project. JMHO.

Comment: What's the problem, anonymous down-voter?

Comment: Do you have something to back up your statements about LGBTQ's visibility?  Cause this seems to be primarily opinion based.

Comment: SCOTUS marriage decision perhaps? DADT being repealed? The ['millennial generation's' shift][1] away from the historical "unnatural" opinion of LGBTQ people? The steadily increasing number of mainstream and popular LGBTQ-themed or inclusive media? The decline of conservative, political dog whistles of the "Gay Agenda" as a [politically manipulative "social issue?"][2]

Comment: There is no doubt that LGBTQ rights and visibility are on the rise and generational negatively on the decline.     [1]: http://www.pewforum.org/2016/05/12/changing-attitudes-on-gay-marriage/   [2]: http://thehill.com/homenews/campaign/246695-young-republicans-say-party-risks-losing-millennials-after-gay-marriage

Comment: Working on non working links in comment.

Comment: Remember that it's a British TV show, so the issues as seen in the U.S. will only be part of it.

Comment: LGBTQ rights are an international topic. U.K. policies in regard to LGBTQ rights are quite progressive, as are the policies in most European  nations and the EU as a whole. I believe the OP is American, as am I, so I'm speaking of US progress.

Comment: I understand that.  My point is that your answer should include European and U.K. perspectives.  Looking at it only from a U.S. perspective  won't answer the question.  I'd also suggest including your links and research in your answer, rather than in the comments.

Comment: The links are for questions in the comments and aren't really relevant to OP question. If you have doubts about the validity of the shift on US public opinion vis-a-vis LGBTQ issues, might I suggest some reading? https://www.bloomberg.com/view/interactives/2015-millennials/  and http://www.gallup.com/poll/191645/americans-support-gay-marriage-remains-high.aspx

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53227/discussion-between-m-mat-and-tim).